# Visual Studio and GIT

Tags: git, visual-studio

I have developed a few solutions each containing more than one project. I want to use GIT to control the WHOLE solution. From my research it would appear that I have to save each project to GIT separately. So the procedure I have been following is:
Load each project in turn and initialise as Git repository for that project and push the project files.

Is there a way to save the WHOLE solution to GIT in one push?

Thanks, thepointyman

Comment: Why do you think each project has to be a separate repository?  You can set up a Git repo in any directory, including one that contains multiple projects.

Comment: On the Git side, this isn't required. Whether VS imposes extra constraints, I don't know. There are pluses and minuses to monorepos (search for that term to read up on them).

Comment: On further investigation I found that loading a multi project solution on my laptop I was offer a GIT option to control the the whole solution. On my two desktops this option is not available and I have to save each project to its own GIT repository. Why can I not see the option to save the whole solution on my Desktop PCs? I am working on my own, no team.